# How to solve this problem in client.cpp and server.cpp problem fatal error: AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, my problem this time is when I do *make*, in this tutorial:
[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient)

my make log is:

*[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.o
/home/rocha/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pkg_cadeira/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:2:36: fatal error: pkg_cadeira/AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rocha/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pkg_cadeira/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/rocha/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pkg_cadeira/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rocha/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pkg_cadeira/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2*

Thanks :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59720/how-to-solve-this-problem-in-client.cpp-and-server.cpp-problem-fatal-error:-addtwoints.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Marlon Rocha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4496/marlon-rocha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved, thanks anyway... I followed the tutorial and put the AddTwoInts.srv in the /srv directory ... :D

---

Originally posted by [Marlon Rocha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4496/marlon-rocha/) with karma: 28 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1